# Does the transition kernel of my application fit into this theoretical setting?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling, markov-process

In my application, I essentially sample random numbers $U^{(m)}\in[0,1)^{\mathbb N_0}$, $m\in\mathbb N_0$, such that $$\operatorname P\left[U^{(m)}\in B\mid U^{(m-1)}\right]=\kappa\left(U^{(m-1)},B\right)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }B\in\mathcal B([0,1))^{\otimes\mathbb N_0},\tag1$$ where $\kappa$ is a Markov kernel on $\left([0,1)^{\mathbb N_0},\mathcal B([0,1))^{\otimes\mathbb N_0}\right)$ and $U^{(0)}$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1)^{\mathbb N_0}$. Now let $k\in\mathbb N$ and $I:=\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$. I don't use the $U^{(m)}$ as they are, but transform them according to $$\left(S^{(m)},X^{(m)}\right):=\left(\lfloor kU^{(m)}_0\rfloor,\left(U^{(m)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right).$$ In order to apply a theoretically established result, I need that the $\left(S^{(m)},X^{(m)}\right)$ evolve according to a Markov kernel $\Sigma$ on $\left(I\times[0,1)^{\mathbb N},2^I\otimes\mathcal B([0,1))^{\otimes\mathbb N}\right)$.

> Are we able to define $\Sigma$ so that the application is actually in the situation of the theory?

I need that $\Sigma$ has a density $\sigma:\left(I\times[0,1)^{\mathbb N}\right)^2\to[0,\infty)$ with respect to $\zeta\otimes\left.\lambda\right|_{[0,\:1)}^{\otimes\mathbb N}$, where $\zeta$ denotes the counting measure on $(I,2^I)$.

You may assume that $\kappa$ has a symmetric density $\rho:[0,1)^{\mathbb N_0}\times[0,1)^{\mathbb N_0}\to[0,\infty)$ with respect to $\left.\lambda\right|_{[0,\:1)}^{\otimes\mathbb N_0}$.

*Remark*: Please take note of my related question: [What is the modified transition kernel induced by this sample truncation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3348584/47771).

Comment: So $S$ here is the integer part and $X$ is the fractional part?  It's a general fact that an injective measurable function of a Markov chain yields another Markov chain.  It doesn't matter whether you have densities or not.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, $S^{(m)}=\lfloor kU^{(m)}_0\rfloor$ (but the $k$ was missing before) and $T^{(m)}=\left(U^{(m)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. I need the density $\sigma$, since it is crucial in the theoretically setting. So, the question is whether the application fits into this theoretical setting or not.

Comment: @NateEldredge To give the full context: The sampler corresponding to $\kappa$ in my application is the one described here: http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Light_Transport_III_Bidirectional_Methods/Metropolis_Light_Transport.html#PrimarySampleSpaceSampler. It's the same as in the comments below [your answer to an other question of me](https://mathoverflow.net/a/337162/91890). The Markov kernel $\Sigma$ which I need to apply a theoretical result, is described [here](https://www.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~hachisuka/mmlt.pdf) on page 5 in the section "final algorithm" (its density is denoted by $q$).

Comment: @NateEldredge Wait a second, if $\kappa$ is basically as in the comments below your answer in the link above, the components of each $U^{(m)}$ are independent, aren't they? This should be helpful.

Comment: @NateEldredge Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3351081/47771.