# If $U$ is a $[0,1)$-valued random variable, does $\lfloor kU\rfloor$ admit a density wrt the counting measure on $2^{\{0,\:\ldots\:,\:k-1\}}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U$ be a $[0,1)$-valued random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, $k\in\mathbb N$, $I:=\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$ and $\zeta$ denote the counting measure on $(I,2^I)$. Does $S:=\lfloor kU\rfloor$ admit a density wit respect to $\zeta$? Clearly, by definition, $$\operatorname P\left[S=i\right]=\operatorname P\left[U\in\left[\frac ik,\frac{i+1}k\right)\right]\tag1$$ for all $i\in I$. If the desired result is wrong in general, are we able to impose assumptions on the distribution of $U$ such that it holds true?

*Remark*: In my application, $U$ is essentially distributed to a mixture distribution $p\mathcal U_{[0,\:1)}+(1-p)\mathcal N_{\mu,\:\sigma^2}$ for some $p\in(0,1)$, $\mu\in[0,1)$ and $\sigma>0$. Please take note of my related question for some context: [Does the transition kernel of my application fit into this theoretical setting?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350595/47771).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Trivially, every integer-valued random variable admits a density with respect to counting measure, and indeed, you have written down exactly what that density is, namely $P[S=i]$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Formally, the density is a function $h:I\to[0,\infty)$ with $$\operatorname P\left[S\in J\right]=\int_Jh\:{\rm d}\zeta\;\;\;\text{for all }J\subseteq I.$$ But you're right. In this trivial scenario, the right-hand side is simply a sum over $j\in J$ and $h(i)=\operatorname P\left[S=i\right]$. I guess I arrived at this confusing point in my distress to solve my other question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350595/47771).