# What is the distribution of this sampled sequence of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, markov-process, sampling

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$
- $X_n$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued random variable for $n\in\mathbb N$
- $\kappa$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$
- $p\in[0,1]$

> Assume we construct a sequence $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued random variables in the following way: With probability $p$ we draw $Y_n$ from $\mu$ **for all** $n\in\mathbb N$ and with probability $1-p$ we draw $Y_n$ from $\kappa(X_n,\;\cdot\;)$ **for all** $n\in\mathbb N$.
>
> I'm confused whether $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ given $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is distributed according to $$E^{\mathbb N}\times\mathcal E^{\otimes\mathbb N}\ni(x,B)\mapsto\bigotimes_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(p\mu+(1-p)\kappa(x_n,\;\cdot\;)\right)\tag1$$ or $$E^{\mathbb N}\times\mathcal E^{\otimes\mathbb N}\ni(x,B)\mapsto p\mu^{\otimes\mathbb N}+(1-p)\bigotimes_{n\in\mathbb N}\kappa(x_n,\;\cdot\;).\tag2$$

Intuitively, it should be $(2)$, but formally it actually seems to be $(1)$. What is correct?

Moreover, I'd be interested in the following: If $\mu$ and $\kappa$ admit densities $f$ and $g$ with respect to a common reference measure $\lambda$, do $(1)$ and $(2)$ admit a density with respect to $\lambda^{\otimes\mathbb N}$? The infinite product seems to be problematic. But is there a density at least when we replace the infinite product with a finite one?

Answer (score 0):

You take the product of measures when you have independence, so $(1)$ would be the conditioned law of $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ where you draw **independtly for each** $Z_i$ whether or not they follow the law $\mu$ with probability $p$.
The conditioned distribution of your sequence $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ would be $(2)$ **assuming** the $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent.

Comment: Actually, I think it's the other way around: Assuming that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is independent, the law of $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ given $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ should be $(1)$. I guess what you mean is that $(1)$ should be the law if we decide for each component separately (with probability $p$) whether we draw from $\mu$ or not. That was my intuition as well! However, when we assume that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is independent and the law of $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ given $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is $(2)$, shouldn't we obtain that $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has uncorrelated components?

Comment: I can't derive that from $(2)$, but from $(1)$. I've asked that before and came to the conclusion that the law cannot be $(2)$, but needs to be $(1)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3351081/47771.

Comment: You don't have uncorrelated components : try with $\mu = \delta_0$ and the $\kappa(X_n,.)$ being positive a.s.

Comment: Please take a look at the question in my link. If $(0)$ holds then it holds $(2)$ (i.e. independent components) with the new definition of $\kappa$ in the answer.

Comment: (a) Do you agree that $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is independent assuming the conditional law is $(1)$? And that $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is *not* independent assuming $(2)$? (b) Does $(2)$ admit a density? It seems like not.

Comment: I took a look, and the new definition of $\kappa$ in the answer corresponds to the case where you choose independently for each $Y_i$.
(a) Yes, I agree (I may be wrong...)
(b) I don't think so.

Comment: Regarding (b): Let $f,g$ be as in the question, $d\in\mathbb N$ and $Q$ denotes $(2)$ with the infinite product replaced by a product from $1$ to $d$. Then we should have $$Q(x,B_1\times\cdots\times B_d)=p\prod_{i=1}^d\mu(B_i)+(1-p)\prod_{i=1}^d\kappa(x_i,B_i)=\int\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}y)\left[p\prod_{i=1}^d1_{B_i}(y_i)f(y_i)+(1-p)\prod_{i=1}^d1_{B_i}(y_i)g(x_i,y_i)\right]=\int_{B_1\times\cdots\times B_d}\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}y)\left[p\prod_{i=1}^df(y_i)+(1-p)\prod_{i=1}^dg(x_i,y_i)\right].$$ So, $Q$ has a density with respect to $\lambda^{\otimes d}$. What do you think?

Comment: Now the same should apply for the infinite product (since we can consider finite rectangles than).